# 555 FlyBack low power

Tags: 555, flyback

I want to build a 555 converter with which to get 3 V AC ~ 100 mA, I stopped at the diagram below. I need help to increase the efficiency of the circuit. Load is VFD display (for filament drive), so I don't need feedback.
Given that the power provided is very low, can I drive mosfet from 555 directly?
I want to find the frequency by testing, depending on the transformer material (100 to 400 kHz).
I want to use this circuit because it is cheap and easy to find / replace in case it breaks down. Dedicated IC ex: SN6501 are hard to find and expensive.

[LMC555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf?ts=1650983626635&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMC555)

[IPB80N04S4-03](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP_B_I80N04S4_03-DS-v01_00-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304328c6bd5c01291c53fc8b5dab)
[image: 555 Flyback diagram]
[image: Waveform]

Comment: NB: Use a mosfet with a VGS compatible with 3.3V/5V. Typically known as a logic level MOSFET.

Comment: Diode D2 will effectively prevent it working well. Remove it.

Comment: Drive the MOSFET through a totem pole.

Comment: If this is just a hobby, or one off design, you can forgo the AC drive of the filament. It'll work just fine for a long time, with only a very slight intensity gradient across the display. Also the filament supply doesn't need to be isolated (not sure if your grounds are connected for sim, or intended to be connected in the final circuit.)

Comment: Just for sim. My vfd need to drive with AC for best performance on long term.